# iOS 7 Custom Back Button disappears after modal ViewController disappeared

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm adding a custom back button to a *UINavigationBar* in *UIViewController* like follows:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  UIBarButtonItem *customBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" " style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(navigateBack)];
  [customBackButton setBackButtonBackgroundImage:barBackBtnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
  [customBackButton setBackButtonBackgroundImage:barBackBtnImgHighlighted forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
  self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = customBackButton;
}
```

It works perfectly until I push a modal *UIViewController* and dismiss it again. What happens is that the standard iOS 7 back button is drawn over my custom back button.

This looks like an iOS 7 bug. Any idea how to work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move your code to *viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated* it should work. It's somewhat a hack, but it should work.